# Break out of a C# instantiated batch script to get a shell?

Tags: c#, batch-file, dos

I am attempting to verify the security of an application. The scenario is this:
A C# WinForms application is run by a limited user via Terminal Services (no desktop, just the app). One of the things this C# app can do is execute a batch file that runs a lengthy process with elevated privileges. I am afraid that the limited user may be able to interrupt the batch script (vua Ctrl+C or some other method) and gain access to the underlying elevated shell.

I have tried to do this myself with various combos of Ctrl+C and Ctrl+Break, etc. All I can get is the "Teminate batch job? (Y/N)" prompt, and if you choose terminate, then control is immediately returned to the C# app (which is good). I have not found a way to break this but it seems dangerous to me.

Does anyone know of a way to break out of a C# instantiated batch script and access the underlying shell without returning to the C# app?

Comment: Can the user do anything to overwrite the batch file, possibly while it's running?

Comment: If you start the process using `Process.Start("cmd.exe script", ..., ..., ...)` make sure the user is not able to spoof the cmd.exe or the script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, don't think there is one. But if you're really worried, why not set the `CreateNoWindow` property on the `ProcessStartInfo` object you are presumably using to `true` to prevent user interaction at all?

Comment: Good suggestion. We want the limited users to be able to see the messages printed from and possibly interact with the batch files (the limited users are a tier-1 support group). We could wrap the shell, redirecting the in/out streams, and add some security there, but I have to prove the current scheme insecure before I can justify that effort.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite an answer to your described scenario but a different way to look at it.

If possible, I would have a "jobs server" who sole responsibility is to run the jobs your Terminal Services-run apps create.  Then you would communicate the job (or just it parameters) via WCF to the server.  The users would have no access to the server and very little control of the jobs (possibly just a cancel option and success/failure status reports).

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this (with a Textbox on your app)

```
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
info.Arguments = "/C ping 127.0.0.1";
info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
info.CreateNoWindow = true;
info.FileName = "cmd.exe";
info.UseShellExecute = false;
info.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
using (Process process = Process.Start(info))
{
    using (StreamReader reader = process.StandardOutput)
    {
        string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
        textBox1.Text += result;
    }
}
```

Then you can see the results of the batch without the users being able to actually see the window at all, that way it's only visible as a process so they can't interupt it.

[image]